# jQuery Get All First Cells Of Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get all tds (cells) of all the rows in a certain table , is there an elegant way to do this or do I need to loop over the collection myself somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `first-child`

```
 $('table tr td:first-child')
 or
 $("table tr td:first")
 or
 $("table tr td").first()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will return all tds inside your table with id=tableId

```
$('#tableId td')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question title is different from your question body. You may be interested in this solution, although I can't be sure:

```
$('#table_id tr td:first-child')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop it

Try this

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function() {
var customerId = $(this).find("td:first").html();    
});
```